# Integrating chatbot in skype

Tags: skype, chatbot, pandorabots

I am wondering if I could commit the chatbot mitsuku (pandorabots) to talk with my friends for me in skype.

Can I do this? If yes, what is a brief plan and what should I study to implement this. (or I can just click one button)

Originally I tried to find out, if I could integrate mitsuku in vk.com (russian social website) or facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I know what you are looking for and don't know how to implement it BUT if I'm not mistaken, Skype has already integrated Mitsuku into its platform in the form of a Smartbot with a bot code of 0a24da83-12a6-4213-931f-54570c35e047